# Grails execute code per-environment

Tags: grails

Is there a way to do what the`Config.groovy` file does, but during the code execution...
Something like:

```
class AController{
    def method(){
        withEnvironments{
            development{
               println 'This is execute just on development'
            }
            production {
               log.debug 'This is execute just on production'
            }
         }
     }
}
```

I know that I can achieve the same effect using `if (Environment.current == 'development')`, but is there something with that sintax???

Comment: just small correction

if(Environment.getCurrent().equals(Environment.DEVELOPMENT))

Comment: @AramArabyan A groovier way of saying that is: `if( Environment.current == Environment.DEVELOPMENT )`

Comment: For lazy groovy developer becomes if (Environment.current == 'development') when the code doesn't have to work :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found [this blog post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/grails-goodness-execute-code-for.html) which shows one possible solution using [`Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment`](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/api/grails/util/Environment.html#executeForCurrentEnvironment%28groovy.lang.Closure%29):

```
import grails.util.Environment

class AController {
  def method() { 
    Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment {
      development {
        println 'This is execute just on development'
      }
      production {
        log.debug 'This is execute just on production'
      }
    }
  }
}
```